# Slow throughput speeds with fusionio iodrive2

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant, vmware-view, fusionio

I recently purchased two HP 380P Gen 8 servers with 365GB IODrive2s for VDI using Vmware View 5.2.

After using the latest HP vmware 5.1 update 1 ESX installer and then installing the [Fusion-io drivers for ESX](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5265066&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_16fdf7e3177b43468b939178ff%257CswEnvOID%253D4115%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) I was able to format the drive as VMFS5, create a pool and put the replica on the Fusion-io.

All of these seemed to run about as fast as our two 15k SAS drives in RAID0. Unsatisfied with the VDI experience we decide to create a pool with all components on the Fusion-io. The speed still didn't seem on par with what the spec sheets state. I finally did a test copy of from the Fusion-io to itself (from the ESXi ssh shell) and I am currently getting about 1GB per minute transfer rate. The white papers claim I should be getting around 500MBps.

Here are some tests:

```
# ls -lrt
rw-------    1 root     root     3572297728 Aug 22 11:43 VMware-VIMSetup-all-5.1.0-947939.iso
# du -h
3.3G    .
```

from 4 drive RAID10 15k SAS to itself:
`cp VMware-VIMSetup-all-5.1.0-947939.iso test.iso` takes 37s

from 4 drive RAID10 15k SAS to Fusion-io:
`cp VMware-VIMSetup-all-5.1.0-947939.iso /vmfs/volumes/fusion2/test.iso` takes 34 sec

from Fusion-io to itself:
`cp test.iso test2.iso` takes 78 sec

from my desktop SSD to itself: 32s

7200rpm hard drive to itself: 115s

---

I currently have a ticket open with HP and VMware but I am essentially getting fingerprinting. I am hoping someone in the community has solved my issues.

Outputs from IOMeter using 8 workers with the all in one access spec for 1 hour:

```
Samsung810 SSD
IOPS        Read IOps       Write IOps      MBps            Read MBps       Write MBps  Transactions per Second
3385.116269 1692.255704 1692.860565 43.364704   21.683055   21.681649   3385.116269

Fusion-io:
IOPS        Read IOps       Write IOps      MBps            Read MBps       Write MBps  Transactions per Second
13172.96404 6570.691766     6602.272278     168.838142      84.220818       84.617323   13172.96404

4disk15kSAS:
IOPS        Read IOps       Write IOps      MBps            Read MBps       Write MBps  Transactions per Second
62854.07353 31429.66595 31424.40759 805.541003  402.802938  402.738065  62854.07353
```

Comment: Moar details! What was wrong with the performance?

Comment: Throughput is 1 GB per minute. This is an unused server I know I may not reach the theoretical 500MB/sec (30GB/min). But 1GB/min is definitively not good. I have tried copying to the 15K SAS raid-10 datastore to the fusionio and fusionio to itself with the same results.

Comment: Sequential I/O throughout isn't the purpose or best measure of an SSD. Latency and random read/write performance is. Can you try a more realistic use-case and see if things look any better?

Comment: I am currently running iometer to get more concrete numbers.

Comment: I haven't used FusionIO with VMWare before so I don't really have any answers for you.. but the performance is definitely not anywhere close to what you should be getting.  Here's what I get creating a 1GB file on FusionIO under CentOS 6.  # time (dd if=/dev/zero of=1gigfile bs=1M count=1024 && sync)
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 0.686625 s, 1.6 GB/s

real 0m1.107s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.689s  So over 1.6GB/sec written, 1.1 seconds to write and sync.

Comment: What model of fusionio are you using?

Comment: Where do the base image, the linked clone, and snapshot disk reside?

Comment: How did you format drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working now. Thanks for all of you help. I wasn't testing the card vs the sas array hard enough. Once I used random writes and reads in testing and saturated the cache on the raid controller, the fusionio beat the array. 168MB/s vs 6 MB/s. I was also able to speed everything up in VDI by enabling a portion of the fusion to be used as host cache.